# How to fetch the values of dynamically generated variables by for loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

```
mydata2 <- maydata1
# x == 10
alpha <- 0.63
beta <- 0.2

for (i in 1:x) {
j <- i +1
  for(i in 1:j){
    CurColumn  <- mydata2[row,paste0("Columns",i)]
    NextColumn <- mydata2[row,paste0("Columns",j)] 
    DiffColumn <- NextColumn - CurColumn
    if ( (CurColumn <= alpha & alpha <= NextColumn) | ( DiffColumn < beta)) {
      mydata2$T1 <- CurColumn
      mydata2$T2 <- NextColumn
      CurActParams  <- mydata2[row,paste0("AP",i)]
      NextActParams <- mydata2[row,paste0("AP",j)] 
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Attached the data frame for reference, i need help in calculating **T1** and **T2**, based on conditions of code.

While executing code i'm not able to exact the column name using paste function, it is returning as a String.

For instance: **"Columns0"** is returned, **mydata$"Columns0"** and what i'm expecting is the column should be like **mydata$Columns0**, so that value can be assigned to new variable.

[image]

Comment: Use `[[...]]` instead `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, hoping it'll be helpful to someone.

```
#x == 10
alpha <- 0.63
beta <- 0.2

for (row in 1:nrow(mydata)) {
        for (i in 0:22) {
          j <- i + 1
          CurColumn  <-
            mydata[row, paste0("Column", i)]
          NextColumn <-
            mydata[row, paste0("Column", j)]
          CurAP  <-
            mydata[row, paste0("AP", i)]
          NextAP <-
            mydata[row, paste0("AP", j)]
          
          Diff <- NextColumn - CurColumn
          
          if (((CurColumn <= myda$alpha) |
               (is.na(CurColumn)))
              &
              ((myda$alpha <= NextColumn) |
               (is.na(NextColumn)))
              |
              (DiffColumn < beta)) {
            mydata$T1 <- CurColumn
            mydata$T2 <- NextColumn
            mydata$V1 <- CurAP
            mydata$V2 <- NextAP
            break
            }
        }
    }
```